# First order ODE question

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> $y' = \dfrac{1}{x+2y}$

This might just be a very easy ODE, but i'm getting stuck somehow.

Let $y=v(x)\cdot x \iff y' = v(x) + x\dfrac{dv}{dx}$

And then $\Rightarrow v(x) +x \dfrac{dv}{dx} = \dfrac{1}{x+2x\cdot v(x)} \iff \dfrac{dv}{dx} = \dfrac{1-x\cdot v(x) -2x \cdot v(x)^2}{x^2 + 2x^2 \cdot v(x)}$

I am not sure how to proceed with that, or maybe it is not the right approach for my problem.

**Many thanks!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The substitution you did was rather complicated. If we say $v=x+2y$ then we have $v’=1+2y’$ so the differential equation is rewritten as $$\frac{v’-1}{2}=\frac1v$$ which is separable

Answer (score 2):

hint...You can write this as$$\frac{dx}{dy}=x+2y$$
Or, $$\frac{dx}{dy}-x=2y$$ and this can be solved with an integrating factor $$e^{\int-1dy}$$

Answer (score 1):

You have $$y' = \dfrac{1}{x+2y}$$

That is $$ \frac {dy}{dx} = \dfrac{1}{x+2y}$$

Thus $$ \frac {dx}{dy} = x+2y$$

This is a linear equation and you can solve it for x as a function of y.

Answer (score 0):

$$y' = \dfrac{1}{x+2y}$$
Consider $x'$ it's easier as a function of the variable y
$$x+2y =x' $$
$$x'-x=2y$$
$$(xe^{-y})'=2ye^{-y}$$
Integrate..
$$(xe^{-y})=2\int ye^{-y} dy$$
$$x(y)=2e^{y}\int ye^{-y} dy$$